# Does SciPy have utilities for parsing and keeping track of the units associated with its constants?

Tags: python, scipy, symbolic-math, scientific-computing

`scipy.constants.physical_constants` returns (value, unit, uncertainty) tuples for many specific physical constants. The units are given in the form of a string. (For example, one of the options for the universal gas constant has a unit field of `'J kg^-1 K^-1'`.)

At first blush, this seems pretty useful. Keeping track of your units is very important in scientific calculations, but, for the life of me, I haven't been able to find any facilities for parsing these strings into something that can be tracked. Without that, there's no way to simplify the combined units after different values have been added, subtracted, etc with eachother.

I know I can manually declare the units of constants with separate libraries such as what's available in SymPy, but that would make ScyPy's own units completely useless (maybe just a convenience for printouts). That sounds pretty absurd. I can't imagine that ScyPy doesn't know how to deal with units.

What am I missing?

Edit:
I know that SciPy is a stack, and I am well aware of what libraries are part of it. My questions is about if SciPy knows how to work with the very units it spits out with its constants (or if I have to throw out those units and manually redefine everything). As far as I can see, it can't actually parse its own unit strings (and nothing else in the ecosystem seems to know how to make heads or tails of them either). This doesn't make sense to me because if SciPy proper can't deal with these units, why would they be there in the first place? *Not to mention, keeping track of your units across your calculations is the exact kind of thing you need to do in science. Forcing manual redefinitions of all the units someone went through the trouble of associating with all these constants doesn't make sense.*

Comment: `scipy` is a collection of different packages, that expand on `numpy` in various ways - sparse, integration, optimization, etc.  So while there is a `constants` module, I don't think the other parts make use of it.  I have seen questions involving a third party module that adds `units`.  It may be linked with an astronomy module.

Comment: `astropy` has a `units` module. `pint` is another units package.  There may be others.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.constants.unit.html

Comment: @hpaulj, Astropy and Pint aren't part of SciPy

Comment: @Alexander, scipy.constants.unit only returns the very unit strings I was talking about. It doesn't actually understand what those units are. If I already have said constants, I don't need a function that tells me what units it has ('I already have those strings'). My question is if ScyPy itself has the ability parse the very strings it provides and keep track of units through mathematical operations.

Answer (score 0):

No, scipy the library does not have any notion of quantities with units and makes no guarantees when operating on quantities with units (from e.g. pint, astropy.Quantity or other objects from other unit-handling packages).